# Media Types for list endpoints

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type

I've got a REST application with endpoints that return single items and pages of those same kinds of item.

Let's say that the single-item endpoint has a media/content type like this:
`application/vnd.company.myitem-1+json`

And we also currently have a content type for the page structure itself, which looks like this:
`application/vnd.company.mylist-1+json`

I really want to be able to specify what the list is a list *of*, but I haven't been able to find an acceptable way to say that it's a `application/vnd.company.mylist-1+json` of `application/vnd.company.myitem-1+json`. Is there any good way to do this or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could encode the list and entry type in a single component of the [vendor tree part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838), such as

   application/vnd.company.mylist1-myitem1+json
   application/vnd.company.mylist1-otheritem1+json

If your list type of item type already contain a dash, you might have to chose an alternative separator.

2. Alternatively you could simply transport the list type in the

   Content-Type: application/vnd.company.mylist-1+json

header and use a different one for the item type such as

```
X-Item-Content-Type: application/vnd.company.myitem-1+json
```

for the item type.

3. **EDIT:** The solution chosen by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468498/nick) was (as described in the comments) to add the item type as a parameter, such as

   application/vnd.company.mylist-1+json; itemtype=vnd.company.myitem-1

Comment: We ended up going with using the extension of the item mediatype as a parameter to the list mediatype: i.e. `application/vnd.company.mylist-1+json; itemtype=vnd.company.myitem-1`
but I like your ideas as well

Comment: Nice, I will add your solution to my answer so that other users can see it clearly.